# jQuery Mobile Text Box AutoComplete feature to enable

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I would like to see browser provided normal autocomplete feature in text-boxes drawn in jQuery-Mobile we applications. I ensured type="text" is given. Here are the input box drawn on browser:-

```
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="scanInfo2" name="BarCodeValue" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
   </fieldset>
```

I would like to see similar autocomplete which we find in email boxes of email sign-in pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that browser's default textbox autocomplete feature kicks-in only if text box is part of `<form>` tag. I re-implemented my screen as having form and textboxes as part of it. It is working fine now on Android browsers.

(but iPhone/IPod) browsers are still not showing autocomplete which I think a problem for some other day.